# Insert query inside of memo Access

Tags: ms-access, report, memo

Is it possible to insert a query or tag inside of an access memo? I would like to create a welcome packet that will include a welcome letter along with other data pulled from Access tables. I can create a new field in a table to store the text i need but i would like to include several other pieces of information pulled from into the report. I would like to insert the data elements as if i was inserting a tag into an html page. The welcome letter should pull in the user's name and the letter address their name and other details individual to the homeowner. The other pages of the report include details about the user that are updated from several locations. Is this even possible in access? If not i will tell users that they must create the welcome letter somewhere else and attach it to the packet manually but it would save a lot of time to be able to print the letter with the packet.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, but there are numerous ways of creating a letter with details from MS Access including a report, MS Word automation, building HTML in code and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by storing the paragraph text in new columns and setting the memo fields to "can grow" in the report. I then seperated the paragraphs with the inserted data. I will also look into Remou's options that he provided as the MS Word automation and HTML in code sound like better options.

Thanks Remou